# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Android application

Tags: java, android, sockets, exception, stream

My android application crashed at this part of the code :

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
Object obj = ois.readObject();
```

when calling the function readObject().

It worked without problems for hours then this happened :

```
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-215
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1937902936, size is 28
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.registeredObjectRead(ObjectInputStream.java:2157)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readCyclicReference(ObjectInputStream.java:833)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:692)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1799)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.readObject(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:766)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1851)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1956)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at com.vittorio.floaty.AcceptThread.run(AcceptThread.java:80)
07-03 07:52:34.409: E/AndroidRuntime(1600):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

How can this happen? I mean the index it's so huge it doesn't make very much sense. Anyway I'm exchanging a serialized object that contains an ArrayList.

Comment: Seems like you have read a bad object.

Comment: Mmh so maybe something wrong happened on the connection link and the receiver had problems reading the object?

Comment: Or maybe a difficult-to-detect bug about deserialization.

Comment: check for sender side whether it is started comunication or not

Comment: ArrayList have custom read and write object methods. If you debug there may be you will figure out why...

Comment: Hey man, I could use some help if possible, I have the exact same problem you have, and it seems there is no plausible reason, and I have found no solutions, did you ever manage to figure out what was wrong?